# Collision detection Graphics 2D

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, collision-detection

I'm building a simulator that is based on car collisions on the road. The "cars" are basic rectangles drawn using `fillRect` and setting random x and y coordinates for each car. The kinematics portion of the simulator work perfect except when cars collide. What I'm trying to do is figure out a way to detect collision without re-inventing the wheel. In essence, is there such implementation in Java that helps with this type of situation?

If not, I have an idea that consists of putting every single x and y point in the area of the square into an array for each car. Then if the other car's "area" overlaps a coordinate with the other, then a collision would occur. Could this be a solution, or is there a simpler way of doing this? Perhaps some advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, I have an idea that consists of putting every single x and y
>   point in the area of the square into an array for each car.

No need to reinvent the wheel. Are you using `Rectangle` objects for your cars underneath? You can call methods such as `contains` and `intersects` which are part of the `Rectangle` api to achieve what you want. You need to make sure you check the next movement of the `Rectangles`, looking for collisions, before you move them.

[Look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).